# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{i}{n}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

> What is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{i}{n}\;\;\;\;,i=\sqrt{-1}$$

Can we say that this limit is $1$? Can a limit in the complex world be a real number? If not what is the limit(if it exists) ?

Comment: Note that $$
\left| {\left( {1 + \frac{i}{n}} \right) - 1} \right| = \left| {\frac{i}{n}} \right| = \frac{1}{n}\to 0.
$$

Comment: Of course all real numbers are complex!

Comment: If you plot the first few numbers in your sequence, I think you'll see it.

Comment: The reason why I couldnt come up with a satisfactory explanation that the limit is in fact 1 is because when we say that the limit of something is 1, we usually think of it as $1.0000....1$ or $0.9999...$ or $1$ itself. However this question suggests that it can also be $1\pm0.000....1i$ which is not even a real number!

Comment: There is no such "number" as $0.000....1i$, just as there is no such "number" as $0.000....1$. The limit is simply $1+0i = 1$.

Comment: Forget about complex numbers for a moment. Would you find it problematic that a sequence of points in $\mathbb R^2$ could converge to a point on the $x$ axis? Because that's all that is happening here.

Comment: @Bungo I think that you are referring to multivariable limits. Coming to think of that, you are right since argand plane is also a 2 dimensional one. Unfortunately I havent learnt them yet(_cries in calc-2_).Thanks for the insight!

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{1}{n+1}=1:$ Can the limit of a sequence of rational numbers be an integer? Yes.  $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{\sqrt 2}{n}=1:$ Can the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers be an integer? Yes. Don't forget that real numbers are complex numbers.

Comment: @newbie105 The complex numbers are often *defined* as simply $\mathbb R^2$ with a multiplication operation and with the notation $(a,b) = a+bi$. So in fact, convergence in $\mathbb C$ is exactly the same thing as convergence in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I agree. Thank you all for the wonderful insight!

Comment: @newbie105: We need parentheses around $1+\frac{i}{n}$ in order to have $\frac{i}{n}$ within the scope of the limit symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a limit in the complex world be a real number?

Yes as the real coordinate axis (X-axis where $y=0$) dwells inside the complex plane $\mathbb C$. Moreover, a complex sequence may approach to its limit point not just only from left or right (as in real axis) but via any direction (*spiral, oblique, etc*).

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{i}{n}) = 1 + i \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}$$
Where:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$
So:
$$1 + i 0 = 1$$

Have to remember that "$i$" is the number like any other.

Comment: @Michael: We need parentheses around $1+\frac{i}{n}$ in order to have $\frac{i}{n}$ within the scope of the limit symbol.